# creating a binary expression tree with post order expression

Tags: tree-traversal

I'm having to create a binary expression tree for the postorder expression

XYZ+AB-C*/-

from what i know, with pupushing opperands into a stack and the popping two out when an operator is next in th list, my best attempt at the binary expression tree is this

```
    -
   / \
  X   / 
       \
        *
       / \
      C   -
         / \ 
        A   B
             \
              +
             / \
            Y   Z
```

is this correct? or am I completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your stack shall look like this when talking about operations and their precedence.

```
X - ((A-B) * C) / (Y+Z)

((A-B) * C) / (Y+Z)

(A-B) * C

(A-B)

(Y+Z)

X
```

So the correct way is Stephan's answer.